# How to vertical align text in the middle without changing size of a div

Tags: html, css

I need to make the text "Hello world" in the left box as (vertical) middle.

If I change CSS

`.red-banner .text {
    background: rgb(32,56,100);
    color: white;
    padding-top:8px;
  }`

then "Hello world" will be shifted a little bit down, but the black background will be shifted also and overlap the below banner.
[image: hello world]

So how can I align the text inside the box vertical middle without changing the size of the black background? (the content of the text is maximal 2 lines).

```css
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px;
}

.right {
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(215,217,216);
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 270px;
}

.left {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

header20 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#inner {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:730px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
}

.banner .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.banner:hover .text {
  display: block;
}

.red-banner .text {
  background: rgb(32,56,100);
  color: white;
}

.green-banner .text {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="row">
    <div class="right">
        <br>      
        <div class="banner red-banner">
          <img src="http://dbclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Red-banner-clipart-image-1.png" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text">
            Hello world.
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <br>
      
        <div class="banner green-banner">
          <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/banner-20clipart-normal_1283818525.jpg" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text">
            Hello world, this is a test message for the effect.
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is a table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is another table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <div id="inner">
            <br>
            <img src="smallpic.png" style='float:left;margin:0.1cm;width:85px;height:85px'>
            <p style='margin-left:2cm;font-size:22.0pt;margin-top:6pt;color:rgb(0,56,96)'><b>This is the title of the page -  bla bla bla <br>Timetable for the next month</b></p> 
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The first line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The second line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The third line of the content</p>
            <br>
        </div>   
   
        <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-right:25px'><img src="pic1.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px'><img src="pic2.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px'><img src="pic3.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `line-height` instead of padding and set it the same with the height of the parent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1: Alignment Using Flexbox

Apply `display: flex;` property to `.text` to make it a flexbox container, and

- Use `justify-content` to **horizontally** align the content.
- Use `align-items` to **vertically** align the content.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px;
}

.right {
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(215,217,216);
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 270px;
}

.left {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

header20 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#inner {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:730px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex; 
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
}

.banner .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.banner:hover .text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.red-banner .text {
  background: rgb(32,56,100);
  color: white;
}

.green-banner .text {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="row">
    <div class="right">
        <br>      
        <div class="banner red-banner">
          <img src="http://dbclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Red-banner-clipart-image-1.png" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text">
            Hello world.
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <br>
      
        <div class="banner green-banner">
          <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/banner-20clipart-normal_1283818525.jpg" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text">
            Hello world, this is a test message for the effect.
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is a table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is another table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <div id="inner">
            <br>
            <img src="smallpic.png" style='float:left;margin:0.1cm;width:85px;height:85px'>
            <p style='margin-left:2cm;font-size:22.0pt;margin-top:6pt;color:rgb(0,56,96)'><b>This is the title of the page -  bla bla bla <br>Timetable for the next month</b></p> 
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The first line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The second line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The third line of the content</p>
            <br>
        </div>   
   
        <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-right:25px'><img src="pic1.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px'><img src="pic2.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px'><img src="pic3.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Option 2: Alignment Using Table & Table Cell

You can use `display: table`. But for this you will have to change your HTML structure a little bit, something like:

```
<div class="text table"> <!-- display: table -->
  <div class="table-cell"> <!-- display: table-cell -->
     Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

then use `vertical-align: middle` & `text-align: center` on `.table-cell` element. Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px;
}

.right {
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(215,217,216);
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 270px;
}

.left {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

header20 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#inner {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:730px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex; 
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
}

.banner .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.banner:hover .text.table {
  display: table;
  height: 50px;
}

.banner:hover .text.table .table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.red-banner .text {
  background: rgb(32,56,100);
  color: white;
}

.green-banner .text {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="row">
    <div class="right">
        <br>      
        <div class="banner red-banner">
          <img src="http://dbclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Red-banner-clipart-image-1.png" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text table">
            <div class="table-cell">
              Hello world.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <br>
      
        <div class="banner green-banner">
          <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/banner-20clipart-normal_1283818525.jpg" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text table">
            <div class="table-cell">
            Hello world, this is a test message for the effect.
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is a table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is another table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <div id="inner">
            <br>
            <img src="smallpic.png" style='float:left;margin:0.1cm;width:85px;height:85px'>
            <p style='margin-left:2cm;font-size:22.0pt;margin-top:6pt;color:rgb(0,56,96)'><b>This is the title of the page -  bla bla bla <br>Timetable for the next month</b></p> 
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The first line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The second line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The third line of the content</p>
            <br>
        </div>   
   
        <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-right:25px'><img src="pic1.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px'><img src="pic2.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px'><img src="pic3.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks Saurav, your idea is clear. Actually, i used `flex` already, but it does not work :(. Sorry, I should not post `.row {
  display: flex; 
}` in CSS in my question because it did not work also. What should I do if my own browser does not support flex. Do you have another solution ?

Comment: @htmlamateur I've used `display: table` & `display: table-cell` in the next part of the answer. I've updated the answer with two options with `flex` (that is already in the answer) & with `table` (that I've appended after flex). Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot Saurav. Your solution is great! :) Have a nice day!

Comment: @htmlamateur Its my pleasure!

Answer (score 2):

Try below css

```
text-align: center;
```

in the text class to align the text

Answer (score 2):

To align item vertically Flex box is the best idea , Old tricks and hacks can do the Job but your layout will need be solid design and flexible , 
So a use of flex box is necessary :
first of all we change the display for the parent item :

```
diplay:flex
```

then we use :

```
justify-content:center to center item horizontally ,
```

and for vertical alignment we use :

```
align-item :center
```

And since you said you cannot use Flex ;
there is another way by using `line-height`

```
.banner:hover .text
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
```

```css
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0px;
}

.right {
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-color: rgb(215,217,216);
  padding-left: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 270px;
}

.left {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin:0px;
  font-family: Calibri;
}

header20 {
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#inner {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width:730px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex; 
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
}

.banner .text {
  position: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.banner:hover .text {
  display: flex;
}

.red-banner .text {
  background: rgb(32,56,100);
  color: white;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.green-banner .text {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" class="row">
    <div class="right">
        <br>      
        <div class="banner red-banner">
          <img src="http://dbclipart.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Red-banner-clipart-image-1.png" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text">
            Hello world.
          </div>
        </div>
      
        <br>
      
        <div class="banner green-banner">
          <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/banner-20clipart-normal_1283818525.jpg" style='width:250px;height:50px'>
          <div class="text">
            Hello world, this is a test message for the effect.
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is a table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table style='width:250px;background-color:rgb(211,238,208)'>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <header20><span style='color:rgb(17,56,96)'><b>This is another table</b></span></header20>
            <ul style='padding-left:25px;margin-top:0px;magrin-bottom:0px'>
                <li>First point</li>
                <li>Second point</li>
                <li>Third point</li>
            </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <br>
    </div>

    <div class="left">
        <div id="inner">
            <br>
            <img src="smallpic.png" style='float:left;margin:0.1cm;width:85px;height:85px'>
            <p style='margin-left:2cm;font-size:22.0pt;margin-top:6pt;color:rgb(0,56,96)'><b>This is the title of the page -  bla bla bla <br>Timetable for the next month</b></p> 
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The first line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The second line of the content</p>
            <p style='margin-left:1cm'> The third line of the content</p>
            <br>
        </div>   
   
        <table align='center'>
        <tr>
            <td style='padding-right:25px'><img src="pic1.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px;padding-right:25px'><img src="pic2.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
            <td style ='padding-left:25px'><img src="pic3.png" style='width:140px;height:115px'/></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. Your idea is as same as Saurav's idea. However, `flex` does not work with my browser :(. Sorry, I should not post .row { display: flex; } in CSS in my question because it did not work also. Do you have another solution ?

Comment: thank you. If I use `line-height`, then the second line of the text will be cut (the content of text might be in 2 lines). I accepted the solution of Saurav, anw, I upvoted for you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the text need to be centered inside divs like this. Hope it will help you.

```
<div class="text">
    <div class="custom-trow">
        <div class="custom-tcell">
            Hello world.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and apply the following CSS rules.

```
.custom-trow {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.custom-tcell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. http://howtocenterincss.com/
Hope it will help you.